# Check if Sequence is Graphic: 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is part of my Discrete Math homework and I have no idea how to solve this.

I am given this sequence: $8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1 $

I have to check whether it is graphic or not.

How do I go on about doing that? Haven't done anything like this before so I'm a bit puzzled. I'm not sure how to solve this, do I have to plot this sequence or what?

Comment: Start with the defintion: a sequence is "[graphic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html)" *iff* it is attained as the [degree sequence of a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29#Degree_sequence).  This condition can be checked algorithmically.

Comment: have you tried applying the [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sequence is graphic if and only if the sequence obtained by deleting the largest degree $k$ and subtracting one to the $k$ largest degrees remaining is graphic.Try to prove this by induction.

hence you get $8,8,7,7,6,6,4,3,2,1,1,1$ is graphic $\iff$

$7,6,6,5,5,3,2,1,1,1,1$ is graphic $\iff$

$5,5,4,4,2,1,0,1,1,1$ is graphic $\iff$

$4,3,3,0,0,1,1,1,1$ is graphic $\iff$

$2,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,$ is graphic $\iff$

$1,0,0,0,0,0,1$ is graphic. So the graph is in fact graphic.

Here is a graph with that degree sequence

[image]

Comment: This is part of my homework ~ therefore I can check online if the solution is correct, unfortunately your solution was incorrect, it said that the sequence isn't graphic. What's going on here? Maybe a mistake on their part?

Comment: Well, I counted the degrees in the graph in the solution and it is correct, are you sure you copied the sequence correctly?

Comment: I mean, you should count the degrees in the graph to make sure, but I can't find more conclusive evidence it is graphic